# Wireless device does not work on Dell Inspiron 3521 after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, inspiron

Wifi does not work at all on Inspiron 3521 after installing Ubuntu 12.04..
When I type in  `lspci -nn`  the wireless device is even not on the list.

Please help in this topic!

Comment: Please edit your question to add details: lspci -nn. Maybe we can spot your wireless device.

Answer (score 0):

Some wireless cards are actually listed as USB.

```
lsusb
```

will show these.

Check your keyboard. I've had several laptops which have a **Fn** blue colored key with a wireless icon above the function key that turns on/off the wireless. This is due to the massive power drain wifis require, so they design a soft power switch for this component.

[These people](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127977/wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-on-dell-inspiron-1750) were able to get it working with a little trick to force the power profile to reset the wifi.