# Ubuntu 14.10 - Lenovo E420 - Wireless is not working

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, thinkpad

Earlier till ubuntu 14.04 the wireless was working for lenovo thinkpad E420, in ubuntu 14.10 it stopped working. Earlier  for ubuntu 12.10 Modified /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and put an entry near the end blacklist acer_wmi to work the wireless.

Now the LAN wired connection is working fine.

Tried couple of solutions provided in the forum but no luck.

A)

```
ThinkPad-E420:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

ThinkPad-E420:~$ rfkill unblock all # Didn't work
```

B)

```
ThinkPad-E420:~$ lspci |grep Network
08:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
```

Installed the driver for realtek RLT8188CE but it didn't work.

Please help to fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried pressing F9? `Hard blocked: yes` usually means a hardware switch has disabled the card. I *believe* F9 is the correct key on this computer.. If it isn't F9 one of the other F keys should have a little wireless symbol on it. Press that one.

Comment: Yes F9 is for the wireless but my thinkpad laptop original keyboad is not working , i am using Logitech wireless K400 keyboad. In this keyboad there is no option to enable or disable the wireless.

Comment: Then in that case you're pretty stuck, as the wireless card appears to be disabled by that key. You *might* be able to get a different keyboard to activate it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You might try something like this http://askubuntu.com/a/143085/44179 no idea if it will work.

Comment: Please let us see: lsmod. As it will be lengthy, paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Thanks.

Comment: Here is the details of the lsmod. http://paste.ubuntu.com/9544786/