# Networking issues following suspend

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, suspend, bluetooth

I'm running a dual boot with ubuntu and windows on my HP laptop and I'm having trouble doing any sort of wireless networking after I suspend it. I cannot connect to wifi, I also seem to totally lose any ability to use bluetooth. (The bluetooth isn't really a huge problem but I thought it was weird). If I click on the wifi symbol in the top right corner it says "wifi disabled by hardware switch" but I don't even know where the switch is (or if I even have one). This only happens when I am running ubuntu, not windows.

I've seen similar issues all over the place and I've tried a few solutions already but nothing seems to work.

I used the script provided in the answer to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) to try and diagnose the problem, the results are here http://pastebin.com/Ga8B1ZW1

If you want to see what it looks like when everything is working, it's here http://pastebin.com/V1Bd8SBY

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem for about a month now, so far without success so if anyone could help it would be amazing.

Comment: Have you tried `Fn`+`Alt`+`F2`? I am presuming your `F2` key has a wireless symbol, else replace `F2` here with the key that has wireless symbol on it.

Comment: I don't have a wireless symbol on any of my keys. I'm pretty sure it's not actually a hardware switch since it happens every time I suspend it and it only happens when I use ubuntu

Comment: I had faced similar issue as yours and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/127977/wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-on-dell-inspiron-1750) answer or `sudo rfkill unblock all` has helped me many times.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those seem to have any effect.