# Wireless Lan gets hard blocked

Tags: intel-wireless

I have just got a new laptop (Dell Inspiron 15) with Windows 10. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 Dual boot with wired internet and it works fine. The wireless does not work. It works when I log into Windows 10. It is hard-blocked. I have spent the better part of a day trying to fix it. I have reinstalled Ubuntu. 
When I do rfkill list all. It says phy0 Wireless LAN Hard blocked: yes.
I tried rebooting too, to no avail.
If I go to Systems Settings > Networks >Wireless.
Airplane Mode was off, but i could switch that on. More importantly, Wireless is OFF and I cannot pull/switch it on. 
Interestingly, when I was installing Ubuntu, it was asking for a password for the wireless adapter (Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)).I had no idea what to do, but I just proceeded without putting a password and the next time with a password and it installed both time.
When I interrut boot, and check in BIOS all wirelss lan/bluetooth are enabled.
The kernel is 3.19.0-25-generic. Which is the only thing I have not tried to update. This post had suggested that ([Cannot Connect To WiFi - Intel Corporation Wireless 3160](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611222/cannot-connect-to-wifi-intel-corporation-wireless-3160)).
I would appreciate if anyone has any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide the wireless_script as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 Paste it here: http://paste.ubuntu.com Give us the link in your reply.

Comment: this one? 
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
chmod +x wireless-info && \
./wireless-info

Comment: Exactly. Paste the resulting output: http://paste.ubuntu.com Please give us the link.

Comment: Will do that asap (am out and dont have computer with me). How about updating the kernel? It is 3.x, would updating it to 4.x fix?

Comment: Without the full diagnostics, it's very hard to speculate.

Comment: chili555,
Please see at http://paste.ubuntu.com/13900145/
Thanks for your help in advance! Would really love to understand this better and also fix it.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/127977/wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-on-dell-inspiron-1750

Answer (score 2):

I notice that you have both `dell-wmi` and `dell-laptop` loaded as modules. Typically, these are helper modules that translate key presses, in your case, the wireless button, into action, turning on and off the wireless.

I wonder if both are intended to be loaded to control the wireless button. Let's try to remove first one and then the other and see if the wireless button now responds to presses. If we succeed, we'll blacklist the errant module.

From a terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r dell-laptop
```

Now try the wireless button. Does it now enable the wireless?

```
rfkill list all
```

If not, reload it and unload the other:

```
sudo modprobe dell-laptop
sudo modprobe -r dell-wmi
```

Now try the wireless button. Does it now enable the wireless?

```
rfkill list all
```

When we determine which, if either, helps, I'll amend my answer to give guidance on how to blacklist the other.

Comment: is it dell-wmi or dell_wmi ? Just wanted to be sure

Comment: It did not help. Tried to remove both modules one by one and check as you suggested. 
I have another laptop which works fine. (in the process of repalcing it).
http://paste.ubuntu.com/13907549/
This is from the other laptop, I have . another Dell. If you see, it looks like it has both modules too (I dont know much but I am guessing looking at the lsmod part). Perhaps comparing the tow might also help you ascertain.

Comment: Also, just to be clear I don't see a physical wireless button on the laptop. There is the On-Off for Wireless in Network through System Settings. But it is locked into Off. I kind of hold down the right mouse and drag it over to On, but it instantaneously switched back to Off.

Comment: When I was installing Ubuntu through the USB drive it was listing the adapter "Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)" and asking me to enter a password. I do not recall seeing that happen in the other laptop. Just additional information, which could help the trouble shooting hopefully. Thanks, so far!

Comment: There *is* a button to press! What is your exact model? Dell Inspirion 15 -what?? What is the F2 button labelled?

Comment: Dell Inspiron 15 i5558-5718SLV Signature Edition Laptop 
http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Dell-Inspiron-15-i5558-5718SLV-Signature-Edition-Laptop/productID.328882600

Comment: There is a Fn button between Ctrl button and The Windows button. should i press that with the F2 button?

Comment: But as you can see from the log file of the other laptop, both modules are there too.

Comment: According to the manual: http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-15-5558-laptop_Setup%20Guide2_en-us.pdf It is Fn+PrtScr. The PrtScr button has a wireless symbol on it.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me until I figured out this combination:

```
#!/bin/bash
rmmod dell laptop
rmmod dell-rbtn
rfkill unblock all
rfkill list
echo "Now press Fn+F1 keys, then wake up your notebook!"
```

You have to put your laptop to sleep, wake up your laptop, and unload the two modules at the top of the above code block before you get it to standby mode by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: I don't have them loaded, but some error.